# npm -v The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever an npm command is fired, it comes with a warning: the system cannot find the path specified. It is not creating any issues while executing. However, it is very distracting at the same time.

Comment: No issues while executing ? where are you executing ?. Please check if $PATH has path to npm installed directory.

Comment: On Windows cmd for executing commands like npm start. I have installed  it in C:\Program Files\nodejs\  directory and the  $PATH variable has the same value : C:\Program Files\nodejs\ . I am not sure what is wrong over here.